# Ubuntu 19.04 slow boot

Tags: boot, time

My boot time is very long. Can somebody help me to reduce it?

This is what I got after I ran `systemd-analyze blame`:

```
     32.964s plymouth-quit-wait.service
     29.180s dev-sda1.device
     15.279s snapd.service
     15.147s networkd-dispatcher.service
     14.075s ModemManager.service
     13.847s udisks2.service
     13.719s apparmor.service
     13.429s systemd-journal-flush.service
     13.245s accounts-daemon.service
     12.129s dev-loop10.device
     11.935s dev-loop16.device
     11.723s dev-loop15.device
     11.307s dev-loop8.device
     11.133s dev-loop9.device
     10.483s dev-loop14.device
     10.394s dev-loop12.device
     10.242s dev-loop7.device
      9.508s grub-common.service
      9.087s avahi-daemon.service
      8.934s apport.service
      8.915s rsyslog.service
      8.897s bluetooth.service
      8.647s dev-loop1.device
```

Answer (score 1):

By looking at the output, I could find that the maximum time is consumed by `plymouth-quit-wait` but note that it cannot be disabled since `Plymouth` is the application which provides the graphical "splash" screen when booting and shutting down an Ubuntu system. I can give a workaround for you so that the machine starts faster.

---

Disable `plymouth` in grub using

```
sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

and change the line `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` into

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="noplymouth video=SVIDEO-1:d"
```

Save the file by using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>x</kbd> + <kbd>y</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>

```
sudo update-grub
```

and then restart the machine

---

Do you use `snap` packages on your system? if no, you can diable `snap`

```
sudo systemctl disable snapd
```

Similarly, disable the services listed below
using the above command. just replace the package name.

```
sudo systemctl disable <packagename>
ModemManager.service
apport.service
accounts-daemon.service
avahi-daemon.service
systemd-journal-flush.service
apparmor.service
```

If you do not use bluetooth, disable it using `sudo systemctl disable bluetooth`

Comment: plymouth didn't get disable

Comment: Yes, I know. I have specified in in the answer and also the reason NOT to disable it.